# What target or targets are built for make dist? Trying to ensure some files are generated

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools

I'm trying to ensure that some non-source files are generated when `make dist` is executed. The files are an info file and an index which is constructed from the info file. I find that the files are generated when I execute `make install` but not when I execute `make dist`.

Here is the Makefile.am. (This is share/logic/Makefile.am in the Maxima project, if anybody cares.)

```
all-local: info

info: logic.info logic-index.lisp

logic.info: logic.texi
    makeinfo --force logic.texi

logic-index.lisp: logic.info
    perl ../../doc/info/build_index.pl $< > $@
```

Somehow I got the idea that the target `all-local` could cause the info and index to be rebuilt. That works OK for `make install` -- I guess `all-local` is a target for that. But `all-local` is not, it appears, a target for `make dist`. What other target could I use to ensure that the logic.info and logic-index.lisp are rebuilt for `make dist` as well as `make install`?

I have searched the web, and SO, and tried some random things, but so far I've come up empty-handed. Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm working with GNU make 3.81, GNU automake 1.14.1, and GNU autoconf 2.69, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force something to be built and included in the package by using `EXTRA_DIST`, so in your case

```
EXTRA_DIST = logic-index.lisp
```

This will cause the file to be always included in the distribution tarball.

Comment: Thanks. I found it necessary to also put in info_TEXINFOS = logic.texi as well, but at any rate it's working as desired for make install and make dist.